# Use the new Siri voices on macOS to render text to audio files

Tags: audio, accessibility, text-to-speech-voices, tts, voiceover

macOS now has a few newly added voices that we can choose from in *VoiceOver Utility > Speech*. I quite like the *Siri Male (United States)* voice, but neither the command `say` nor using Automator will let me select this or any other Siri voices to use. So far I could only use the voice with the hotkey to read out loud selected text.

Is there a way to use those new voices to render text to audio files?

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62680596/7669319

Answer (score 0):

If you search for the Record It Audio Device for MacOS and install it, you can use Quicktime Player to create audio files pf Siri voices speaking, using the method you mentioned to read aloud selected text.

Answer (score 0):

The [say man page](https://ss64.com/osx/say.html) shows that there is a -v argument available to select the voice. I'm not sure if the examples on this page are out of date but should be a good starting point.